# Brackets balance in expression

Tags: php, brackets

> Determine whether the given string is balanced; that is, whether it
>   consists entirely of pairs of opening/closing brackets (in that
>   order), none of which mis-nest. Possible brackets: () [] {}.

I have proposed the following solution:

```
<?php

function isBracketsBalanced (string $input) : bool {

  $costs = [
    '[' => 1, '(' => 10, '{' => 100,
    ']' => -1, ')' => -10, '}' => -100
  ];
  $brackets = str_split ($input);
  $opened = [- $costs [end ($brackets)]];
  $balance = 0;

  while (($bracket = array_pop ($brackets)) !== NULL) {

    $cost = $costs [$bracket];
    $balance += $cost;

    if ($cost < 0)

      $opened [] = - $cost;

    else if ($cost == end ($opened))

      array_pop ($opened);

    else

      return FALSE;
  }

  return $balance == 0;
}
```

Reviewer's summary: the problem is solved at a good, but not high enough level.

Can someone explain what exactly in the solution I proposed is at an "not high enough level"?

Comment: Oh dear, this totally stinks of an X-Y problem. Whatever you are trying to do, there is probably a better way.Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Can we get an example string?

Comment: Perhaps the reviewers wants you to solve it using OOP? Your reviewer is very vague, bias and this has a XY problem smell.

Comment: Framed as homework.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/SandyPriceyDevices

Comment: It's not about OOP.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with array_pop(), I'm just not seeing how your *cost* related code factors in since thats not one of the problem requirements: there is no mention of priority in the problem between bracket types. The only requirement is that each opening bracket has a corresponding closing bracket, without mis-nesting.

array_pop() implies a stack which would be ideal for this problem. Push opening symbols on to the stack, as they are encountered. When a closing symbol is found, it should match the top of the stack, if not, return false for unbalanced; otherwise pop it off the stack and proceed in like fashion until the end of the string.

You don't even need an array for your stack. You could use a string that begins as empty.